# How to update object in array, only if object property is equal to search term

Tags: mongodb

Here is dummy JSON:

```
{
    "_ID": ObjectId('xdfdsf'),
        "array": [
            {
                "name": "Jon",
                "permissions": [
                    "update",
                    "delete",
                    "create"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Ben",
                "permissions":[
                    "update"
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

And so on. I want to create a query that will search the array, find element in array which has name "Ben" and pushes new permission into the array.

It's probably relatively simple to do but I got completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$` positional operators to do such `updates`.

Try this :

```
db.collection_name.update({
    "array.name" : "Ben"
},{
    $push : {
        "array.$.permissions" : "new_permission"
    }
}
```

Read more about [$(update) positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in official MongoDb docs for detailed information.

Comment: Haha, yes, I just posted my own answer, I was missing the "$", I guess it's monday for you, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Zoti's answer was incorrect, but I finally got it working:

```
db.myCollection.update( { "array.name": "Ben"}, {$push: {"array.$.permissions": "read"}})
```